# Store input from a text field in a PHP variable

Tags: php, html

Store the users input from a text field in a variable. Any ways to do this?

Comment: Do one of the zillion tutorials out there, this question seems just plain lazy to me.

Answer (score 5):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" />
```

PHP-onsubmit (untested)

```
<?php
   $firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry to ask such a dumb question.

Comment: what's there to test? In the worst case scenario, it will generate a notice.

Comment: Untested...  Sheesh, you mean you couldn't be bothered to write a full unit test and a selenium interface test suite for this answer?  Talk about lazy... ;-)

Comment: I think a lazy question deserves a proportional response.

Answer (score 3):

if you have a form with that textarea and you submit that form, you'll have the value in your global `$_GET` or `$_POST`-array (depending on whats the methot of your form).

you can access this value by typing `$_GET['nameofyourtextarea']` (or the same with `$_POST`)