# is there any way i could make the first row as mandatory before going to second row in codeigniter?

Tags: html, codeigniter

My view:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
           <div class="form-group">
                <label>Employee Id</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control"   placeholder="Enter employee id"   name="empid">
                </div>
       </div>



           <div class="col-md-3">
             <div class="form-group">
                <label>Employee Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control"   placeholder="Enter employee name"   name="empname">
                </div>
       </div>


         <div class="col-md-3">

        <div class="form-group">
                <label>Order Number</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control"   placeholder="Enter order number"   name="ordernumber" value="<?php echo $order_number;?>">
                </div></div>




                  <div class="col-md-3">

        <div class="form-group">
                <label></label>
                <a onclick="myFunctionfirst()" class="form-control">Proceed to order Create</a>


                </div></div>
```

Once you click on 'proceed to order create' the second row is created. I want this to happen only when the first 3 fields in first row are filled. Please suggest on this

And this is my controller:

```
public function index()
 {
     $empid = $_POST['empid'];


    If ($empid == ""){

     $this->load->model('invoice_model');
    $data['stat']=    $this->invoice_model->get_stationary();


     $data['order_numbers']=  $this->invoice_model->get_countnumber();
    $data['order_number']= $data['order_numbers'][0]->count+1;
     $data['page']='invoice/invoice_view';
     $this->load->view("template",$data);
 }
 }
```

And it's throwing an error undefined index empid

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow. what you can do is save the input as a variable [Store input from a text field in a PHP variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088082/store-input-from-a-text-field-in-a-php-variable/4088106)

this method is however a bit unsafe. to secure the input you can use https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlspecialchars.asp
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

and once you have the variables just simply check if the variable is empty or not

```
public function index()
     {
        $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];


        If ($firstname != ""){

            $this->load->model('invoice_model');
            $data['stat']=    $this->invoice_model->get_stationary();


            $data['order_numbers']=  $this->invoice_model->get_countnumber();
            $data['order_number']= $data['order_numbers'][0]->count+1;
            $data['page']='invoice/invoice_view';
            $this->load->view("template",$data);
        }
     }
```

`$_POST` is how the data is being send.  here they explain the difference between `POST` and `GET` https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-PHPs-get-method-post-method

'firstname' is the name of the input. in your case its `<input type="text" class="form-control"   placeholder="Enter employee id"   name="empid">` so it should be `$_POST['empid']`

the data is being send with the submit button. instead of using the `<a>` tag you should use the `<button type="submit">` tag also, wrap the inputs in a form tag.

Comment: where do i use this: <?php
   $firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
?>  It comes in  'Store input from a text field in a PHP variable'

Comment: edited the post for you, if you need any other explenation just ask

Comment: I tried that in controller. Getting error Message: Undefined index: empid

Comment: is the function in the same file as the html? also, can you edit the post to the current code you have right now so I know if you didn't made any mistake?

Comment: public function index()
     {
         $empid = $_POST['empid'];


        If ($empid == ""){

         $this->load->model('invoice_model');
        $data['stat']=    $this->invoice_model->get_stationary();
        
        
         $data['order_numbers']=  $this->invoice_model->get_countnumber();
        $data['order_number']= $data['order_numbers'][0]->count+1;
         $data['page']='invoice/invoice_view';
         $this->load->view("template",$data);
     }
     }

Comment: please edit it in the original post so it's easier for me to read :) and also, is the function index() in the same file as the html or is it in a different file

Comment: as i said, you need to swap the `<a onclick="myFunctionfirst()" class="form-control">Proceed to order Create</a>` for an `<input type="submit">` tag. this actually submits the data towards the backend of the page
and you need to wrap the code in a `<form>` tag so it defines the method of sending (POST) in this case.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot come on anything like that.

Comment: this is my submit button:<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>   how do i change it?

Comment: hi I need further assistance on this

Comment: can somebody please help me?